# Как отметить в форме, а именно в select multiple "option value selected" выбранные ранее пункты?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть форма, при помощи которой отправляю данные в базу. Также, есть форма для редактирования этих данных. В эту форму подставляю данные из базы, чтоб пользователь мог видеть введенные им ранее данные. С input проблем нет: `value="<?php echo $name ?>"`
А вот с select option value не получается, там может быть несколько пунктов. Выбранные ранее пользователем пункты хранятся в базе в виде строки через запятую. Мне нужно их отметить как выбранные в select option value.
Как такое можно реализовать? Спасибо.

```html
<li>
            <label for="name">Название компании, бригады или ваше имя:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>" maxlength="51"  name="name" placeholder="Название компании, бригады или ваше имя" required />
        </li> 
        <li>
        <label for="specialisations">Выберите, на чем специализируетесь</label>
        <select name="specialisations[]" multiple required>
  <option value="Земляные работы">Земляные работы</option>
  <option value="Бетонные работы">Бетонные работы</option> 
  <option value="Кладочные работы">Кладочные работы</option>
  <option value="Фасадные работы">Фасадные работы</option> 
  <option value="Кровельные работы">Кровельные работы</option>
  <option value="Стяжка">Стяжка</option>
 </select>
        </li>
```

Comment: Поиск по строке - `strpos` \ `mb_strpos`, находится ли значение в массиве - `in_array`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Пробую, но никак не могу понять, мне использовать цикл в каждом option value? Не могли бы Вы привести пример фрагментом кода? Извините за наглость.

Comment: Посмотри в колонке справа __Похожие__ вопросы

Comment: Использовал in_array, все получилось. Большое Вам спасибо!